# How do I use Streambuilder to copy data from one document and paste it into another in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem with my flutter application that leverages firebase/firestore. The following code is attempting to copy data from a document in one collection and take that data from that document and copy it into another document in a different collection. However, when I run the code with some breakpoints I noticed that whenever the function is called it skips over the Streambuilder line. If you could help me out that would be appreciated. I have put the error in one function.

Code:

```
copyDocument(String copyId) async {
    bool beingCalled;
    var createdAt;
    String chattingWith, id2, nickname, photoUrl;
    DocumentReference collectionRef = Firestore().collection('messages').document(id).collection('pastchats').document(copyId);
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> (
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('messages').document(copyId).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          print('waiting...');  
          return CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 2,
          );
        } else {
          beingCalled = snapshot.data['beingCalled'];
          chattingWith = snapshot.data['chattingWith'];
          createdAt = snapshot.data['createdAt'];
          id2 = snapshot.data['id'];
          nickname = snapshot.data['nickname'];
          photoUrl = snapshot.data['photoUrl'];
          Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
            await transaction.set(
              collectionRef,
              {
                'beingCalled': beingCalled,
                'chattingWith': chattingWith,
                'createdAt': createdAt,
                "id" : id2,
                'nickname': nickname,
                'photoUrl': photoUrl,  
              },
            );
          }
        );       
        }
      },
    );
    }
```